# Не работают события keyup/keypress/keydown

Tags: javascript, jquery, вёрстка, события, javascript-events

Необходимо сделать следующий функционал, чтобы при вводе символов с клавиатуры в input вызывалось модальное окно и то что юзер ввел в первом инпуте отобразилось во втором. Но проблема в том что события keypress/keyup/keydown не реагируют на ввод в инпут. Модалка открывается только после клика на нее лкм. В чем может быть проблема?

Небольшое демо привел ниже.

```js
$("#input").keypress(function() {
  const vl = $(this).val();

  $(this).magnificPopup({
    items: {
      src: '#modal',
      type: 'inline',
    },
    focus: '#modal_input',
    fixedContentPos: true,
    callbacks: {
      open: function() {

        $("#modal_input").val(vl);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/magnific-popup.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="some text" id="input">
  </form>
  <div id="modal" class="mfp-hide">
    <div>Hello i am a modal window</div>
    <input id="modal_input" type="text">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Это более подробная версия [этого вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/742490/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-keyup-keypress) Здесь добавлена демка с проблемой и примером кода.

Comment: А по какому событию должен выводится popup? Сразу же, как пользователь ввёл первый символ? Или когда закончил ввод?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не правильно работает событие keyup/keypress](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/742490/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b5-keyup-keypress)

Comment: @Stargazer Думаю сразу же как ввел 1 символ, возможен вариант срабатывания события после определенного количества символов для удобства.

Comment: @Darth Да, верно. Это я вчера задавал, но без демки. Решил задать новый немного доработанный вопрос для привлечения большего внимания пользователей.

Comment: @ConstantineShibaev стоило либо отредактировать старый вопрос, либо удалить его

Comment: @Darth Удалил, надеюсь это вас успокоило))

Comment: Я вот фиддл набросала https://jsfiddle.net/ptf9w7q5/7/ . Типа так должно быть?

Comment: @Stargazer Да, все так, только не понимаю почему у меня это не работало, ведь пробовал же и так $(this).magnificPopup.open() и так $.magnificPopup() единственное что не пробовал это все это сложить  как вы описали убрать this и добавить .open

Answer (score 2):

Не дружу я с JQ, мне по душе чистый JS

```js
document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('input', function(){
  document.getElementById('modal_input').value = document.getElementById('input').value;
  if(document.getElementById('input').value !== 0){
  document.getElementById('modal').className = 'modal';
  }
})
```

```css
.modal{
background:red;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" placeholder="some text" id="input">
</form>
<div id="modal" class="mfp-hide">
  <div >Hello i am a modal window</div>
  <input id="modal_input" type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: querySelector для id это не тру. getElementById работает сильно быстрей. 
Голос за чистый js)

Comment: @Darth, благодарю, буду знать... А в чем именно разница? и в каких условиях лучше то или то использовать?

Comment: Почти в два раза - https://jsperf.com/getelementbyid-vs-queryselector.
Про условия все довольно очевидно - если вам надо получить элемент по id, используете getElementById, в остальных случаях - что то другое)

Comment: @Darth, благодарю еще раз... не знал что такая разница... Хорошая критика, лучше любого урока...))